# How can I get Emails through Microsoft Graph from the last hour?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to get emails for a user from the last hour. This is the code I tried:

DateTime Object:

```
DateTime filter = new DateTime();
filter = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1);
```

Call to Graph:

```
await graphClient.Users[broker.Id].MailFolders.SentItems.Messages.Request().Filter(string.Format("SentDateTime ge '{0}'", filter.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))).GetAsync();
```

I get a Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException:

> A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'GreaterThanOrEqual'.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Are you looking for only items sent by the user? And is there a reason for just the last hour rather than "since last we checked"?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Yes only sent items. Is there such a request I can make? The plan was to make that request every hour. But if I could get emails "since last we checked" I would strongly consider using that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to integrate delta queries to be able to query a user's mail, and then the next time query all the new mail that has some to that user since the last query.

We have documentation that shows just how to do that here: [Get incremental changes to messages in a folder](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_messages)

I know this does not address your main question, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to make these delta queries using the interface you guys provide (like the way I did it in my question)? Otherwise, I am unsure of how to make the requests in code. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use add the Delta() method to grab a the delta result. If you're interested in seeing some code in action, the unit test for deltas in the SDK is a great place to start - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dec97e6bbb57940b3f823a7dfe887a11d7f6845b/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Test/Requests/Functional/DeltaQueryTests.cs